# How to pull json from api and convert to dataframe or table for use with arcpy

Tags: python, python-2.7, api, arcpy

I am trying to read in data from the CDC 500 cities API for integration into a larger spatial analysis. I am writing out a python script using arcpy and a couple other libraries.

The three big steps are:
1. read in and convert data to proper format
2. join data to census tract shapefile
3. tabulate intersection to recalculate to the ZCTA level

However, there's some kind of formatting issue and it can't execute the join table tool.

I'm new to python, but I have tried reading in the data with response.read() as well as using the json library with json.dumps() and json.loads(), but neither seem to be doing what I want.

Here's what I have right now:

```py
Url="https://chronicdata.cdc.gov/resource/47z2-4wuh.csv"
Query='?PlaceName='
SelectedCity=raw_input('Enter the city of interest')

#define function to check for valid input
def hasNumbers(inputString):
    return any(char.isdigit() for char in inputString)

#create if then statement to print an error if the input is not a string
#will need to change the elif statement to identify special characters
#We could just pull in all the data, convert to point shapefile and then clipped to area of interest....
if hasNumbers(SelectedCity) == False:
    Request=Url+Query+SelectedCity.title()
    print('You\'re API request URL:' + Request)
else:
    print("That input does not match any possible city name")

#open the request defined above
response=requests.get(Request)

#read file to json
Json=json.dumps(response.content)
saveData = open("jsonOutput.json", "wt")
saveData.write(Json)
saveData.close()

censusTract=tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(parent= tkObj,title='Select City Census Tract File')
myMessage = 'Census Tract={0}'.format(censusTract)
print(myMessage)

#fieldmapping
fieldmappings = arcpy.FieldMappings()
fieldmappings.addTable(censusTract)
fieldmappings.addTable(saveData)

zipFieldIndex = fieldmappings.findFieldMapIndex('GEOID')
fieldmap = fieldmappings.getFieldMap(zipFieldIndex)

#Get the output field's properties as a field object
field = fieldmap.outputField

#Rename the field and pass the updated field object back into the field map
field.name = 'GEOID'
field.aliasName = 'GEOID'
fieldmap.outputField = field

#create input names
inlayer=censusTract
infield="GEOID"
jointable=response
joinfield="TractFIPS"

CDCshape = arcpy.AddJoin_management(inlayer,infield,jointable,joinfield)
```

The result from this should be a shapefile with the CDC 500 cities data joined OR a dataframe that could be manipulated with pandas or other libraries and then joined to a shapefile.

Comment: requests has a .json method.  r = requests.get(url).json()

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Pandas to read the csv file into a data frame. And then you can filter, clean and merge the data. Install pandas is it is not already installed

```
pip install pandas
```

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

Url="https://chronicdata.cdc.gov/resource/47z2-4wuh.csv"

file_ouput=pd.read_csv(Url)
print(file_output)
```

To convert the dataframe to json

```
file_json = file_output.to_json(orient='records')
```